# Intellij deprecation warning for java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap

IntelliJ seems to think that the no-arg constructor of `java.util.HashMap` is deprecated, as judged by the style in which it marks up the constructor name:

[image]

How can I fix it, if I don't want to disable inspections?

UPD: IntelliJ seems to think that the `java.util.HashMap` *class* is deprecated

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's weird. `java.util.HashMap` is most certainly not deprecated at all.

Comment: what have you set as project sdk?

Comment: are you using a code quality tool? Some of them tend to highlight constructor uses and wrongly interpreter them as a bad practice.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko They usually highlight these issues with a red curvy line (like a compiler error), not by striking the code snippet.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch JDK 1.8.0_121

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I'm not using such tools

Comment: Are you quite certain that the strikethrough​ is because it's indicating deprecation, and not some other situation?

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, see new screenshot that I've just added

Comment: But when I open HashMap.java, there is no @Deprecated annotation

Comment: That's because, as others mentioned, `HashMap` is not deprecated.

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, I want to say that problem not in sources

Comment: I just changed my test project sdk from 1.0_131 to 18.0_121 and do neither get the warning no do I see a @Deprecated annotation in the docs. Which  jdk do you have? Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Oracle JDK

Comment: that's strange; I have the very same version here without that. Can you please click on the 'Edit Source' button in the documentation window (the fourth from the left) and check wether the source has the deprecated  annotation? And if so, click the 'scroll from source' in the project window to see where the source is loaded from?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Source is loaded from HashMap.java and there is no such annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue with java.util.List marked as deprecated. Somehow I had marked it as such via an "external annotation".

**To remove it:**

- Click through to the source (in my case java.util.List)
- There should be a @ beside the type, click on it ...
- Deannotate java.lang.Deprecated

[image: The external annotation on List]

Comment: I guess I did the same)

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded and set the latest JDK 1.8_131 and problem has been solved.
Thank you for attention

UPD: When I choose again former JDK the problem no longer occurs

Comment: glad it worked out for you; although I would have liked to know the reason for this strange behaviour.